# How to Type Chars From Android KeyBoard(Virtual) in Robotium

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

please give any suggestion except than solo.clickOnText(). It doesn't work.

and also I don't want to use enterText() either, as that is not a good alternative.

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear on what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

[1] type " a " on text box

[2] solo.sendKey(97); // here 97 is ascii key code of character " a ".

Here i represent a nice example.

```
public void testAutomation_typetext()
{

    solo.clickOnEditText(0);
    ch_array = "ashtemp123@gmail.com".toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<ch_array.length;i++) 
    {
      solo.sendKey( fun_get_android_keycode(ch_array[i]) );
    }
}


  public int fun_get_android_keycode(char ch)
  {  
       int keycode = ch;//String.valueOf(ch).codePointAt(0);
       Log.v(TAG,"in fun : "+ch+" : "+keycode + "");

       if(keycode>=97 && keycode <=122)
       {
           Log.v(TAG,"atoz : "+ch+" : "+keycode + " : " + (keycode-68));
           return keycode-68;   
       }
       else if(keycode>=65 && keycode <=90)
       {
           Log.v(TAG,"atoz : "+ch+" : "+keycode + " : " + (keycode-36));
           return keycode-36;   
       }
       else if(keycode>=48 && keycode <=57)
       {
           Log.v(TAG,"0to9"+ch+" : "+keycode + " : " + (keycode-41));
           return keycode-41;   
       }
       else if(keycode==64)
       {
           Log.v(TAG,"@"+ch+" : "+keycode + " : " + "77");
           return KeyEvent.KEYCODE_AT;
       }
       else if(ch=='.')
       {
           Log.v(TAG,"DOT "+ch+" : "+keycode + " : " + "158");
           return KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PERIOD;
       }
       else if(ch==',')
       {
           Log.v(TAG,"comma "+ch+" : "+keycode + " : " + "55");
           return KeyEvent.KEYCODE_COMMA;
       }
       return 62;
}
```

i hope this will help in your best automation test case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that for now. See http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers and look for Keyboard.